# SwiftでのWebViewの戻るボタンを実装したい

Tags: swift, xcode

WebViewのallowsInlineMediaPlaybackをtrueにして、なおかつ戻るボタンを設置したいのですが、うまく行きません。
下記のプログラムだとビデオのインライン再生はできますが、戻るボタンが動作しません。
どうすればよろしいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

```
// WebView.swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var webView: WKWebView!
    var urlString: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        config.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []

        let webView =  WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }

        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
    
    // 前のページに戻る
    func goBack() {
        webView.goBack()
    }
}


// ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
private var webView = WebView(urlString: "https://hogehoge123.jp/")

var body: some View {
    VStack() {
        webView
        
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                webView.goBack()
            }, label: {
                Text("前に戻る")
            })
        }
    }
}
```